# promise error in navTrl.push()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to build a simple function that will let me navigate through different pages in my app. I want to be able to pass the name of the page where I want to go in my html code. What I did so far is

In my home.ts

```
`goToPage(test){
    console.log('clicked! '+test);
    this.navCtrl.push(test);
}`
```

In my home.html

```
<button ion-fab color="light" (click)='goToPage("ChooseCharacterPage")'>
```

Everything loads, but when I click I get

```
invalid page component: ChooseCharacterPage
convertToView @ nav-util.js:23
NavControllerBase.push @ nav-controller-base.js:54
HomePage.goToPage @ home.ts:19
View_HomePage0.handleEvent_13 @ /AppModule/HomePage/component.ngfactory.js:193
(anonymous) @ view.js:408
(anonymous) @ dom_renderer.js:276
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:227
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
e.runGuarded @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
i @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
e.runGuarded @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
i @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
error_handler.js:53 Error: Uncaught (in promise): false
    at s (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at Object.ti.reject (nav-controller-base.js:187)
    at NavControllerBase._queueTrns (nav-controller-base.js:197)
    at NavControllerBase.push (nav-controller-base.js:52)
    at HomePage.goToPage (home.ts:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_HomePage0.handleEvent_13 (/AppModule/HomePage/component.ngfactory.js:193)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.<anonymous> (view.js:408)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dom_renderer.js:276)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
e.runGuarded @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
i @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
```

What puzzles me is the promise problem since the variable is passed with the click of the button. SHouldn't a promise problem arise only if and when the var is undefined?

Comment: This isn't a promise problem. The error message is in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @suraj says, you need to send a Component to the push method (and not a string). But maybe a simpler approach could be to declare a property in your ts code, assigning the `ChooseCharacterPage` component class:

```
public chooseCharacterPage: any = ChooseCharacterPage;

// ...

goToPage(test: any){
    this.navCtrl.push(test);
}
```

And then in your view you can use that variable:

```
<button ion-fab color="light" (click)='goToPage(chooseCharacterPage)'>
```

Please notice that in the html we're now using the property (the name starts with lowercase, and it's not between quotes).

Comment: this looks like a neat solution,thank you
 just to understand better, you called chooseCharacterPage a property, to me looks like a variable to wich you can assign any type of value, that is public so accessable by every script (in my app or just in my home.ts?), am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, it's public but since it's declared inside your `HomePage`, it can be used only inside that component and its view. If you want to use it outside that component, you'll need to grab the component by using `ViewChild` from the parent component, but I can't think of any advantage of doing that, since it's just a simple property.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `ChooseCharacterPage` in the `click` event in your code:

```
<button ion-fab color="light" (click)='goToPage("ChooseCharacterPage")'>
```

You are actually passing a *string literal* which obviously is not a component.
For passing objects you will not have any inner quotes.
If the page component object is not present in the view you should directly import in the component side and call

`this.navCtrl.push(ChooseCharacterPage)`

without passing it as a parameter in the event function call.
**or** in your Function

```
gotoPage(page:string){
switch(page){
  case "ChooseCharacterPage": 
    this.navCtrl.push(ChooseCharacterPage);
    break;
  //other cases
  }
}
```

Comment: if I take away the quotes
    <button ion-fab color="light" (click)='goToPage(ChooseCharacterPage)'> 
the variable is undefined, and if I add id directly to the function I will have to create a funcion for every single page in my app. Isn't there a way to pass a variable to push()? maybe something like stringfy() that can turn my string into a value that push can recognize?

Comment: maybe create a switch map in the function. Mapping the string literal to the page class

Comment: no..It needs the page class directly..will edit answer with example

Comment: thank you for your help, but doing that way I would have to write more code than if I had to create different functions for every page.

Comment: ok.. I guess @sebaferreras answer should work for you. set a localvariable with the page